# if $X\subseteq Y$, then $\bar{X} \subseteq \bar{Y}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $X$, $Y$ be arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, show if $X\subseteq Y$, then $\bar{X} \subseteq \bar{Y}$

**Proof**

since $Y\subseteq \bar{Y}$

$\bar{Y}$ contains all the adherent points of Y by definition

then $\bar{Y}$ contains all adherent points of $X$ ($X\subseteq Y$)

$\implies \bar{X}\subseteq\bar{Y}$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: It seems correct

Comment: Yes. $X\subseteq Y\subseteq\overline Y$, and since the closure of $Y$ is closed, and the closure of $X$ is the smallest closed set containing $X$, it must be that $\overline X\subseteq \overline Y$.

Comment: I didnt prove yet that the closure of Y is closed

Comment: @MAS I believe Pedro is taking the *definition* of $\overline{X}$ to be "the smallest closed set containing $X$".