# Is true that if $A\subseteq B$ then $\operatorname{interior}(A)\subseteq \operatorname{interior}(B)$?

Tags: general-topology

Is true that if $A\subseteq B$ then $\operatorname{interior}(A)\subseteq \operatorname{interior}(B)$, where $\operatorname{interior}(A)$ denotes the largest open set contained in $A$?

Comment: It would help if you gave us some context for the problem, and if you told us what you tried and where you got stuck so that we can better help you.

Comment: Also, there are multiple definitions of the closure.  What's yours?

Comment: If $A \subset B$ then $A \subset \overline{B}$ and then $\overline{A} \subset \overline{B}$. A similar approach works for the interior.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086417/if-x-subseteq-y-then-barx-subseteq-bary?rq=1) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620296/if-a-subset-b-then-bara-subset-barb?rq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226075/prove-that-if-a-subseteq-b-then-bara-subseteq-barb?rq=1).  One of them is probably a duplicate of your question depending on your definitions used.  There are other similar questions here for the question about interior rather than closure as well.  Please remember to try to search before posting.

Comment: Sorry but for internal part is true?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\bar{A}$? Please, make your question as precise as possible, and show what you have already tried to do. We can then, help you. This community is not aimed to solve the problem of the others, but to help them to find some solution. :)

Comment: I would like an help with internal part

Comment: @Peppe I see. Can you define what it means? Please define the concepts, and then state the proposition properly.

Comment: The internal part of A is the biggest open that is contained in A

Comment: Then $\mathrm{int}(A)$ is open and it $\subseteq A\subseteq B$, so..

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{int}(A)$ is open and as $\operatorname{int}(A) \subseteq A \subseteq B$ it is *an* open subset of $B$, so it's a subset of the *largest* open subset of $B$, hence $\operatorname{int}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(B)$.

This uses the definition of interior as:

$$\operatorname{int}(A) = \bigcup\{O: O \text{ open in } X, O \subseteq A\}$$

and that for $\operatorname{int}(B)$ we can take $O = \operatorname{int}(A)$ as one of the sets we're taking the union of.